# Should there be a tag for MySQL InnoDB Cluster?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-creation

There are a lot of different MySQL tags, but there's no tag for [MySQL InnoDB Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-userguide.html). So maybe there should be a `mysql-innodb-cluster` tag?

Also, now that there are two MySQL Cluster products, would it make sense to rename the `mysql-cluster` tag to `mysql-ndb-cluster`? Or is this what tag synonyms are for?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this makes sense.

Although InnoDB Cluster is still relatively new, as it was released only a year ago (see [MySQL InnoDB Cluster GA is Available Now!](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-innodb-cluster-ga/)), there are several examples of questions here on DBA.SE that could have been tagged with `mysql-innodb-cluster`:

- [MySQL InnoDB cluster pricing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198999/mysql-innodb-cluster-pricing)
- [how to resolve innodb cluster conflict](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186268/how-to-resolve-innodb-cluster-conflict)
- [Is InnoDB Cluster a viable alternative to MySQL NDB cluster, and MySQL Fabric](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185095/is-innodb-cluster-a-viable-alternative-to-mysql-ndb-cluster-and-mysql-fabric) (this one was closed)
- [MySQL InnoDb Cluster Replication Issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202624/mysql-innodb-cluster-replication-issue)
- [MySQL InnoDB or MySQL NDB Cluster which one to use](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/201603/mysql-innodb-or-mysql-ndb-cluster-which-one-to-use/201672)
- [InnoDB Cluster Read-Only Lag Behind Writer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193776/innodb-cluster-read-only-lag-behind-writer)
- [mysqld slowly eats memory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192351/mysqld-slowly-eats-memory)

Also, in further support of this proposal, I will add that InnoDB Cluster is featured prominently on the [MySQL Documentation pages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) where there's a link to it at the top of every page. (It's right there at the top, just to the left of 'MySQL NDB Cluster'.) So it's very much 'a thing' to be reckoned with.

Comment: Would you [create the tag wiki and excerpt details](https://dba.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/2057) for the tag?

Comment: @MaxVernon Already working on it :)